# Graphql and Mongoose: Cannot return null for non-nullable field

Tags: mongoose, apollo-server, typegraphql

I have a simple setup using type-graphql, Apollo server and Mongoose:

```
  @Query(() => User)
  async getUser(@Arg('id') id: string) {
    return UserModel.findById(id)
  }
```

This basic resolver produces this error: "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.id."

There is an easy fix: calling `UserModel.findById(id).toObject()` or `UserModel.findById(id).lean()`, so that mongoose produces a simple object instead of a document.

I would like to understand why I have to add "lean" or "toObject" everytime I return something from a resolver. All the exemple I found online to combine Mongoose and Graphql do not add this boilerplate code. Maybe type-graphql wrap to reducer with some code which is not able to understand a Mongoose document (which rely on 'get' and 'set' functions)?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but on `return await AnswerModel.find({ question })`. Your fix didn't work for me. Did you figure out what was the actual issue?

Comment: I do not remember exactly what was the underlying problem, but it was a misleading error actually. You might want to take a look at this issue: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1989

Comment: I checked that issue before coming here. Anyway I fixed my issue. Thanks